# I need help fixing an error when I upload a database into myPHPadmin

Tags: mysql

I am trying to restore a wordpress site and upload the database backup into myPHPadmin.

After uploading my database, i get the following:

```
Error
SQL query: 

# Table: `staging_wp_options`

# Delete any existing table `staging_wp_options`

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `staging_wp_options`;

MySQL said: 

#1046 - No database selected
```

---

how do I fix?

Answer (score 0):

you haven't specified which database you want to use before uploading your backup file.
Go to phpmyadmin, in the left bar go to your database by clicking on it (or if you want, create a new one). then Go to import tab and import your file.